# How to prevent Fabric task (in serial mode) from being executed on other hosts when error occurs on one of the hosts list?

Tags: python, fabric

In serial mode, when one of my host has detected a error, I want to cancel the task on all the other following hosts but don't want to exit the whole code.

How to do it?

Code example:

```
target_hosts = [host1, host2, host3]
execute(function, hosts=target_hosts)
print "Hello world"
```

If error happens on `host2`, I don't want `function` continues on `host3`, but still want to print `Hello world`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to find the right approach without knowing what you are trying to do inside the `function`. To my knowledge, Fabric's `execute` doesn't provide any error handling, so you have to do it by yourself. Try something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fabric.api import run, execute, settings

def fce():
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        if run('echoo $HOSTNAME').failed: # this will fail
            return False

    return True

target_hosts = [host1, host2]
for host in target_hosts:
    out = execute(fce, host=host)
    if not out[host]:
        break

print "Hello world"
```